# What is the HTTP status code of the response when the request implement IReturnVoid?

Tags: servicestack

What is the HTTP status code of the response when the request class implement IReturnVoid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the response is `void` then you should return a `204 No Content` status.

```
Response.StatusCode = 204;
Response.StatusDescription = "No Content";
```

This is particularly important for JSON requests, as returning a `200 Success` with no content is considered invalid JSON.

You can use a filter to check for `void` responses and automatically set this. *In you `AppHost` `Configure` method:*

```cs
GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, dto) => {
    if(res.StatusCode == 200 && dto == null) {
        res.StatusCode = 204;
        res.StatusDescription = "No Content";
    }
});
```